# Styling issue in Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Looking at the generated Assembly.styles.css there are IDs or whatever it is called.

[image]

But these IDs are not appearing in the generated HTML.

[image]

Which results that the styling does not become applied.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS isolation is a build step, so it does not work when [Razor runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is enabled.

Make sure that you haven't enabled runtime compilation of your Razor files.

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33446)

Comment: You are right. I had enabled Runtime Complation using `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`. Removing that, the issue became resolved.